# SiftGPU cannot be compiled

Tags: ros, slam, navigation, rosmake, rgbdslam-freiburg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How do I get around this?

```
$ rosmake rgbdslam_freiburg 
[ rosmake ] rosmake starting...                                                 
[ rosmake ] Packages requested are: ['rgbdslam_freiburg']                       
[ rosmake ] Logging to directory /home/jackson/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20160116-082026
[ rosmake ] Expanded args ['rgbdslam_freiburg'] to:
['rgbdslam']                
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> roslang [ make ]                                       
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< roslang  No Makefile in package roslang                
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rospy [ make ]                                         
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rospy  No Makefile in package rospy                    
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> roscpp [ make ]                                        
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< roscpp  No Makefile in package roscpp                  
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> geometry_msgs [ make ]                                 
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< geometry_msgs  No Makefile in package geometry_msgs    
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> sensor_msgs [ make ]                                   
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< sensor_msgs  No Makefile in package sensor_msgs        
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> opencv2 [ make ]                                       
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< opencv2 ROS_NOBUILD in package opencv2                 
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> image_geometry [ make ]                                
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< image_geometry ROS_NOBUILD in package image_geometry   
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> bullet [ make ]                                        
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> rosconsole [ make ]                                    
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< bullet ROS_NOBUILD in package bullet                   
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> angles [ make ]                                        
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< rosconsole  No Makefile in package rosconsole          
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> rostest [ make ]                                       
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< angles ROS_NOBUILD in package angles                   
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> roswtf [ make ]                                        
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< rostest  No Makefile in package rostest                
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> message_filters [ make ]                               
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< message_filters  No Makefile in package message_filters
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> std_msgs [ make ]                                      
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< roswtf  No Makefile in package roswtf                  
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> tf [ make ]                                            
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< tf ROS_NOBUILD in package tf                           
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosbag [ make ]                                        
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< std_msgs  No Makefile in package std_msgs              
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> pcl [ make ]                                           
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosbag  No Makefile in package rosbag                  
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosbuild [ make ]                                      
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< pcl ROS_NOBUILD in package pcl
 No Makefile in package pcl
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> roslib [ make ]                                        
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosbuild  No Makefile in package rosbuild              
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> smclib [ make ]                                        
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< roslib  No Makefile in package roslib                  
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> pluginlib [ make ]                                     
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< pluginlib ROS_NOBUILD in package pluginlib             
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> bond [ make ]                                          
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< smclib ROS_NOBUILD in package smclib                   
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosservice [ make ]                                    
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< bond ROS_NOBUILD in package bond                       
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> bondcpp [ make ]                                       
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< bondcpp ROS_NOBUILD in package bondcpp                 
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> nodelet [ make ]                                       
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosservice  No Makefile in package rosservice          
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< nodelet ROS_NOBUILD in package nodelet                 
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> dynamic_reconfigure [ make ]                           
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> common_rosdeps [ make ]                                
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< common_rosdeps ROS_NOBUILD in package common_rosdeps   
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> cv_bridge [ make ]                                     
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< cv_bridge ROS_NOBUILD in package cv_bridge             
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< dynamic_reconfigure ROS_NOBUILD in package dynamic_reconfigure
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> nodelet_topic_tools [ make ]                           
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> visualization_msgs [ make ]                            
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< visualization_msgs  No Makefile in package visualization_msgs
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< nodelet_topic_tools ROS_NOBUILD in package nodelet_topic_tools
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> octomap_ros [ make ]                                   
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> pcl_ros [ make ]                                       
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< pcl_ros ROS_NOBUILD in package pcl_ros                 
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> nav_msgs [ make ]                                      
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< octomap_ros ROS_NOBUILD in package octomap_ros         
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> actionlib_msgs [ make ]                                
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< actionlib_msgs  No Makefile in package actionlib_msgs  
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> trajectory_msgs [ make ]                               
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< nav_msgs  No Makefile in package nav_msgs              
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> std_srvs [ make ]                                      
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< trajectory_msgs  No Makefile in package trajectory_msgs
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> arm_navigation_msgs [ make ]                           
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< arm_navigation_msgs ROS_NOBUILD in package arm_navigation_msgs
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> flann [ make ]                                         
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< flann ROS_NOBUILD in package flann                     
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> mk [ make ]                                            
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< mk  No Makefile in package mk                          
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> orocos_kdl [ make ]                                    
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< std_srvs  No Makefile in package std_srvs              
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> octomap_server [ make ]                                
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< orocos_kdl ROS_NOBUILD in package orocos_kdl           
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> python_orocos_kdl [ make ]                             
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< python_orocos_kdl ROS_NOBUILD in package python_orocos_kdl
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< octomap_server ROS_NOBUILD in package octomap_server   
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rgbdslam [ make ]                                      
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> kdl [ make ]                                           
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< kdl ROS_NOBUILD in package kdl
 No Makefile in package kdl
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> eigen_conversions [ make ]                             
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< eigen_conversions ROS_NOBUILD in package eigen_conversions
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> tf_conversions [ make ]                                
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< tf_conversions ROS_NOBUILD in package tf_conversions   
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> cv_markers [ make ]                                    
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< cv_markers ROS_NOBUILD in package cv_markers           
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> opencv_tests [ make ]                                  
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< opencv_tests ROS_NOBUILD in package opencv_tests       
[ rosmake ] All 34 linesgbdslam: 1.2 sec ]           [ 1 Active 47/48 Complete ]
{-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  mkdir -p bin
  cd build && cmake -Wdev -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=`rospack find rosbuild`/rostoolchain.cmake  ..
  [rosbuild] Building package rgbdslam
  [rosbuild] Including /opt/ros/fuerte/share/roslisp/rosbuild/roslisp.cmake
  [rosbuild] Including /opt/ros/fuerte/share/rospy/rosbuild/rospy.cmake
  [rosbuild] Including /opt/ros/fuerte/share/roscpp/rosbuild/roscpp.cmake
  
  ------------------------------------------------------------------
  
  Compiling SiftGPU...
  make[1]: Entering directory `/home/jackson/ros/rgbdslam_freiburg/rgbdslam/external/siftgpu/linux'
  mkdir -p ../../../build/siftgpu
  mkdir -p ./bin 
  ln ../data/ -d -s -f
  g++ -o ../../../build/siftgpu/GLTexImage.o ../src/SiftGPU/GLTexImage.cpp -g -O2 -I../include -fPIC -L/usr/lib64 -L/usr/lib -L./bin -Wall -Wno-deprecated -pthread   -march=native -mfpmath=sse -c 
  In file included from ../src/SiftGPU/ShaderMan.h:31:0,
                   from ../src/SiftGPU/GLTexImage.cpp:40:
  ../src/SiftGPU/ProgramGLSL.h: In member function ‘virtual void* ProgramGLSL::GetProgramID()’:
  ../src/SiftGPU/ProgramGLSL.h:67:52: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
  /tmp/ccEycrJt.s: Assembler messages:
  /tmp/ccEycrJt.s:352: Error: no such instruction: `vfmadd312ss 8(%rsp),%xmm0,%xmm1'
  /tmp/ccEycrJt.s:385: Error: no such instruction: `vfmadd312ss 24(%rsp),%xmm0,%xmm1'
  /tmp/ccEycrJt.s:407: Error: no such instruction: `vfmadd312ss 20(%rsp),%xmm0,%xmm1'
  make[1]: *** [../../../build/siftgpu/GLTexImage.o] Error 1
  make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/jackson/ros/rgbdslam_freiburg/rgbdslam/external/siftgpu/linux'
  
  ------------------------------------------------------------------
  
  CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:123 (MESSAGE):
    SiftGPU cannot be compiled.  Returned: 2
  
  
  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
[ rosmake ] Output from build of package rgbdslam written to:
[ rosmake ]    /home/jackson/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20160116-082026/rgbdslam/build_output.log
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rgbdslam [FAIL] [ 1.25 seconds ]                       
[ rosmake ] Halting due to failure in package rgbdslam. 
[ rosmake ] Waiting for other threads to complete.
[ rosmake ] Results:                                                            
[ rosmake ] Built 48 packages with 1 failures.                                  
[ rosmake ] Summary output to directory                                         
[ rosmake ] /home/jackson/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20160116-082026
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/224273/siftgpu-cannot-be-compiled/) by [jacksonkr_](https://answers.ros.org/users/21619/jacksonkr_/) on ROS Answers with karma: 396 on 2016-01-16

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JonW](https://answers.ros.org/users/317/jonw/) on 2016-01-16**:
Your issue seems to match the one in this answer:
[rgbdslam-v2-catkin_make-error](http://answers.ros.org/question/190688/rgbdslam-v2-catkin_make-error/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In CMakeLists.txt there was an option to disable using sift. In numerous installs I only saw this option a couple of times. I can't remember it off the top of my head but it started with `SET` had `sift` somewhere in the line and ended with `1)`. All you have to do is change the `1` to a `0` and sift is disabled.

---

Originally posted by [jacksonkr_](https://answers.ros.org/users/21619/jacksonkr_/) with karma: 396 on 2016-01-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0